# Based on country code of http_cookie preference rewrite to the appropriate sites on Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

How to route based on cookies preferred by the end user?
 We have Nginx/1.17.10 running as pod in AKS. eCommerce site is hosted on this.
 CloudFlare is front end acting as DNS and WAF.
 CloudFlare have GeoIP turned on , so we have parameter - $http_cf_ipcountry to trace the country code. however we are looking for the preference saved by end user and route to that specific region.

Example:

```
If $http_cookie --> COUNTRY_CODE=UAE;
Then rewrite to example.com --> example.com/en-ae
If $http_cookie --> COUNTRY_CODE=KW;
Then rewrite to example.com --> example.com/en-kw
If there is no preference saved on cookie, then route to default "example.com"
```

Http_cookie parameter also holds other detail such as _cfduid, COUNTRY_CODE_PREV, CURRENYCY_CODE , EXCHANGE_RATE

What should be the best approach to handle this requirement? 
Anyone help me on this, thanks!

Comment: Am I getting you right. You are sending a cookie along with the HTTP-Request. In case my answer is not using the right variable to get the cookie value you can share more details about the cookie. I will edit my answer then.

Comment: Below is $http_cookie value: `"_fbp=fb.1.1579739518938.1290691001; cto_bundle=xxxx; _ga=xxx; ...._gid=GA1.3.378961375.1587548967; __stgeo=\x220\x22; visitorId=ad743657-3f13-44d9-83d2-cd15ade6b204; user_country=KW; ......; user_country_selection=KW"'`

Comment: Nginx version is 1.17.10, don't see the map module enabled, do we need nginx plus?

Comment: Just checked it again to be sure. http_map_module is available in NGINX OpenSource as well. I am not sure what binary of NGINX are you using. To make sure your version of NGINX is build with the map module could you please run `strings \`which nginx\` | grep ngx_http_map_module | head -1` for me and share the result.

Comment: `root@nginxweb-767474c9fc-xdstg:/# strings \`which nginx\` | grep ngx_http_map_module | head -1
ngx_http_map_module` this confirm is this enabled ?  Can you please have a look oncookies, tried like $http_cookie_USER_COUNTRY didnt help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a map to handle construct the redirect URLs.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

This will set the rewrite url to a variable $new_uri. The default, if no cookie value is present, will be /en-en/. Now you can create a rewrite rule.

```
 rewrite ^(.*)$ $new_uri permanent;
```

Here is an updated config example as requested.

```
map $cookie_user_country $new_uri {
    default /en-en/;
    UAE /en-ae/;
    KW /en-kw/;
}


server {
        listen 8080;
        return 200 "$uri \n";
}

server {
        listen 8081;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $new_uri permanent;
        return 200 "$cookie_user_country \n";
}
```

Use the `$cookie_NAME` directive to get the right value of a single cookie. The `$http_VAR` contains the value of a specific HTTP request header.

See my curl request for more details.

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# curl -v --cookie "user_country=KW; test=id; abcc=def" localhost:8081
* About to connect() to localhost port 8081 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:8081
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: user_country=KW; test=id; abcc=def
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.17.6
< Date: Sun, 26 Apr 2020 12:34:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Location: http://localhost:8081/en-kw/
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.6</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

#### Checking current running NGINX Binary contains map module

type

```
strings `which nginx` | grep ngx_http_map_module | head -1
```

This will list all "printable" strings from the nginx binary and grep the output by "ngx_http_map_module". The result should look like this:

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# strings `which nginx` | grep ngx_http_map_module | head -1

--> ngx_http_map_module
```

If the output is eq to ngx_http_map_module the current running NGINX binary was compiled with map support. If not -> make sure you are using a NGX Binary compiled with map support.